# Java/Kotlin Kafka Consumer using for multiple instances (container) in web app

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka

For my Spring boot web app, after the application starts, I want to call a method of a class to keep it running until the app shutdowns.

However if my application is deployed to Kubernetes cluster, so it would normally have multiple instances of the web app, let's say 4 instances (so I assume there will be 4 instances of `KafkaConsumer` as well). I am wondering whether the following piece of code is thread safe or can be horizontal scale?

As when my app stops, I got some warning like following: 
`kafka consumer is not safe for multithreaded access`

```
@Component
class KafkaConsumerService : ApplicationRunner {
  private lateinit var kafkaConsumer: KafkaConsumer<String, String>

  init {
    val props = Properties()
    props[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "127.0.0.1:9092"
    props[ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG] = "AnotherDemoConsumer"
    props[ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java.name
    props[ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java.name

    kafkaConsumer = KafkaConsumer(props)
  }

  override fun run(args: ApplicationArguments?) {
    receiveFromKafka()
  }

  fun receiveFromKafka() {
    kafkaConsumer.subscribe(listOf("test-topic"))

    while (true) {
      val consumerRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(3000)

      consumerRecords.forEach { record ->
        logger.info("Receive Kafka message having key: ${record.key()}, value: ${record.value()}, " +
            "partition: ${record.partition()}, offset: ${record.offset()}")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: does kubernetes pods creates new instance? or access the same instance ?

Comment: I think k8s pods should create new instance of the app? So it should be safe? But still not quite sure the warning about not thread safe.

Comment: according to this warning i believe pods are not creating new instances, if they use same consumer instance, then multiple threads are accessing same consumer instance.  which results this error messages